# WKWebView and NSURLProtocol not working

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift, ios8, wkwebview

When using the old UIWebView you could catch the requests by implementing a custom NSURLProtocol. I us this to handle requests that requires authentication.

I tried the same code and it doesn't work with the new WKWebView but my protocol class isn't called at all. Is someone experiencing the same problem or is there a better way of doing authentication with the WKWebView?

Without any modifications I get a 401 response in the decidePolicyForNavigationResponse delegate function. I've also tried connection to the server with a NSURLConnection and handling the authentication with a NSURLConnectionDataDelegate. That works but the stored credentials isn't picked up by the WKWebView.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

#### Updated answer for iOS 11 and macOS 10.13

Since iOS 11 it is possible to declare an object that conforms to the  `WKURLSchemeHandler` protocol and register it in the `WKWebView` configuration: `-[WKWebViewConfiguration setURLSchemeHandler:forURLScheme:]`.

#### Old answer

`WKWebView` makes requests and renders content out-of-process, meaning your app does not hear the requests they make. If you are missing a functionality, now is the time to open a bug report and/or an enhancement request with Apple.

As of iOS 10.3 SDK, `WKWebView` is still unable to make use of custom `NSURLProtocol`s using public APIs.

---

Enterprising developers have found an interesting method:
[`+[WKBrowsingContextController registerSchemeForCustomProtocol:]`](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebKit2/UIProcess/API/Cocoa/WKBrowsingContextController.mm#L103)
It supposedly adds the provided scheme to a list of custom protocol handled schemes and should then work with `NSURLProtocol`.

Comment: So, so disappointing. Has Apple given any reason for this change?

Comment: @Alex The out-of-process makes it difficult to implement.

Comment: Thanks for updating this for the latest iOS SDKs! Pretty disappointing it's still not supported... hope lots of radars have been opened to make this a reality.

Comment: This was added in iOS 11.

Comment: No, HTTP protocols are not allowed. I have not looked if it might be possible using private API.

Comment: @RamaniHitesh Your code JS nothing to do with this issue. Please don’t spam.

Comment: Did anyone tried to submit app with using private API?

Comment: @Neftanic If you are going to use private API, at least do minimal attempt to hide it. You can search Google how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

`WKWebView` has a `navigationDelegate` property. If that delegate is set `WKWebView` will call the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge` method on that delegate if the method is implemented. You need to place your authentication code in this method. Example:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential *))completionHandler {
    NSURLCredential *credential = [[NSURLCredential alloc] initWithUser:@"bob"
                                                               password:@"pass"
                                                            persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceNone];
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeUseCredential, credential);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach: https://github.com/WildDylan/WKWebViewWithURLProtocol/tree/master/Example/WKWebViewWithURLProtocol

It may be uses private API - i'm not sure ;)

Comment: This is interesting, albeit written strangely. All that is needed is calling `[WKBrowsingContextController registerSchemeForCustomProtocol:@"schemes"];`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using URLProtocol just for authentication, there is some other way to achieve that.

Like when u got a error code -1202 from didFailLoad, and make a URLConnection to do the authentication thing, reload the page after.

Actually I need to using URLProtocol with WKWebView also, lol~

Comment: I tried that solution but WKWebView didn't pick up the credentials after reload

Comment: sorry to hear about that ,if u got any news, pls info me